# Despite RVM-plugin Jenkins uses wrong ruby version

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, jenkins, rvm, hudson

Jenkins is running on an ubuntu machine. It has a special user jenkins which is used for executing the jobs.
RVM is installed and in an ssh shell on the server, logged in as the jenkins user, everything works fine.(If I set RVM to use ruby 1.9.3 `ruby -v`returns 1.9.3 as version)
I use the RVM-plugin for Jenkins and have set it to use 1.9.3

**Output by Jenkins for RVM:**
      Capturing environment variables produced by 'rvm use 1.9.3'
      $ bash -c export
      $ bash -c "test -f ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
      $ bash -c "test -f /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
      [workspace] $ bash -c " source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm use --install --create 1.9.3 && export > rvm.env"
      Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0

---

However if I later want to execute my script it uses ruby version 1.8.7.

**Output for ruby version and environment:**

```
  + which ruby  
  /usr/bin/ruby  
  + ruby -v  
  ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]  
  + rvm info  

 ruby-1.9.3-p0:  

  system:  
      uname:       "Linux h1332957.stratoserver.net 2.6.32-042stab078.27 #1 SMP Mon Jul 1 20:48:07 MSK 2013 i686 GNU/Linux"  
      bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)"  
      zsh:         " => not installed"  
   rvm:  
      version:    "rvm 1.9.2 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"  
   ruby:  
      interpreter:  "ruby"  
      version:      "1.8.7"  
      date:         "2010-01-10"  
      platform:     "i486-linux"  
      patchlevel:   "2010-01-10 patchlevel 249"  
      full_version: "ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]"  
   homes:  
      gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0"  
      ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0"  
   binaries:  
      ruby:         "/usr/bin/ruby"  
      irb:          "/usr/bin/irb"  
      gem:          "/usr/bin/gem"  
      rake:         "/usr/bin/rake"  
   environment:  
      PATH:         "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin"  
      GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0"  
      GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global"  
      MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0"  
      IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/.irbrc"  
      RUBYOPT:      ""  
      gemset:       ""
```

**Question:**
How can I make Jenkins use ruby version 1.9.3 instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by sourcing rvm.
I updated my script to look like this:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
 rvm use 1.9.3
 rvm info
```

Now the output by rvm info is correct.
Most important are the first and second line.

Output by `rvm info`:

```
 ruby-1.9.3-p0:

   system:
     uname:       "Linux h1332957.stratoserver.net 2.6.32-042stab078.27 #1 SMP Mon Jul 1 20:48:07 MSK 2013 i686 GNU/Linux"
     bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)"
     zsh:         " => not installed"

   rvm:
     version:      "rvm 1.9.2 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

   ruby:
     interpreter:  "ruby"
     version:      "1.9.3p0"
     date:         "2011-10-30"
     platform:     "i686-linux"
     patchlevel:   "2011-10-30 revision 33570"
     full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]"

   homes:
     gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0"
     ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0"

   binaries:
     ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby"
     irb:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/irb"
     gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/gem"
     rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rake"

   environment:
     PATH:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
     GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0"
     GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global"
     MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0"
     IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/.irbrc"
     RUBYOPT:      ""
     gemset:       ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Rvm creates a environment file on your workspace called "rvm.env". If you add:

`source rvm.env`

to all your shell scripts, you'll get the right environment without having to set up rvm manually.

Answer (score 1):

Adding "rvm use x.x.x" didn't work for me. But it did produce a helpful error message:

> RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
>
> You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
>   Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
>   Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.

My terminal emulator was already allowing login shell too.

Adding "--login" to the bash call got it to work.